# MySQL Right Outer Join Null Value, Standings(Rankings) With All Users

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a standings(rankings) query.

I use tables `users`, `schedule` and `picks` to calculate the standings. However the flaw with this is if a user has not submitted any picks that user will not show up in the standings.

The query below returns all users that have submitted picks. User 2 and user 4 have not submitted picks and there for does not show up.

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| userID | userName | totalWins | totalLost | totalPushs | totalPoints | totalBets | trueBets |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1    |   aaaa   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   3    |   cccc   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   5    |   eeee   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

I'm trying to create it where all users will show up in the standings regardless if they have submitted a pick or not. Like below.

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| userID | userName | totalWins | totalLost | totalPushs | totalPoints | totalBets | trueBets |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1    |   aaaa   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   2    |   bbbb   |     0     |     0     |     0      |      0      |     0     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   3    |   cccc   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   4    |   dddd   |     0     |     0     |     0      |      0      |     0     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   5    |   eeee   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

However, I'm getting this returned

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
| userID | userName | totalWins | totalLost | totalPushs | totalPoints | totalBets | trueBets |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   1    |   aaaa   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  NULL  |   NULL   |     0     |     0     |     0      |      0      |     0     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   3    |   cccc   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|  NULL  |   NULL   |     0     |     0     |     0      |      0      |     0     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
|   5    |   eeee   |     0     |     0     |     1      |     0.5     |     1     |    0     |
+--------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+
```

I have gotten to the point where I am trying to RIGHT OUTER JOIN `users` table where all the users resides to the query but NULL values are showing as expected because of no matches.

How would I be able to replace those NULL values with the correct `userID` and `userName`

This is my code

```
SELECT
    lt.userID,
    lt.userName,
    IFNULL(lt.totalWins,0) AS totalWins,
    IFNULL(lt.totalLost,0) AS totalLost,
    IFNULL(lt.totalPushs,0) AS totalPushs,
    IFNULL((totalWins+(totalPushs*.5)),0) AS totalPoints,
    IFNULL(totalWins+totalLost+totalPushs,0) AS totalBets,
    IFNULL(totalWins+totalLost,0) AS trueBets
FROM (
    SELECT
        userID,
        userName,
        SUM(win) AS totalWins,
        SUM(lost) AS totalLost,
        SUM(push) AS totalPushs
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            (finalResult = 'win') AS win,
            (finalResult = 'loss') AS lost,
            (finalResult = 'push') AS push
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                users.userID,
                userName,
                IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult
            FROM
                users
            JOIN
                picks 
            ON
                users.userID = picks.userID
            JOIN
                schedule
            ON
                picks.gameID = schedule.gameID
            WHERE
                weekNum <= 1
        ) x
    ) x
    GROUP BY
        userID
) lt
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    users
ON
    users.userID = lt.userID
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Your issue is because of the `join` in the second subquery. This is meaning that it doesn't have anything to join back to users at a later date. Start simple and build up. I'd recommend rewriting your query to start from users and left join `picks` and `schedule` and use a group by to get the results you want instead of so many nested queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took [Doug's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3192719/doug) recommendations to start with `users` table and reworked the code.

Finally got what I needed.

Instead of `JOIN` I used `LEFT JOIN` and also changed `WHERE weekNum <= 1` to `WHERE (weekNum <= 1 OR weekNum IS NULL)`

Code below

```
SELECT
    *,
    (totalWins+(totalPushs*.5)) AS totalPoints,
    totalWins+totalLost+totalPushs AS totalBets,
    totalWins+totalLost AS trueBets
FROM (
    SELECT
        userID,
        userName,
        IFNULL(SUM(win),0) AS totalWins,
        IFNULL(SUM(lost),0) AS totalLost,
        IFNULL(SUM(push),0) AS totalPushs
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            (finalResult = 'win') AS win,
            (finalResult = 'loss') AS lost,
            (finalResult = 'push') AS push
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                u.userID,
                userName,
                IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult
            FROM
                users AS u
            LEFT JOIN
                picks AS p
            ON
                u.userID = p.userID
            LEFT JOIN
                schedule AS s
            ON
                p.gameID = s.gameID
            WHERE
                (weekNum <= 1 OR weekNum IS NULL)
        ) x
    ) x
    GROUP BY
        userID
) x
ORDER BY
    totalPoints DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT
    lt.userID,
    lt.userName,
    IFNULL(lt.totalWins,0) AS totalWins,
    IFNULL(lt.totalLost,0) AS totalLost,
    IFNULL(lt.totalPushs,0) AS totalPushs,
    IFNULL((totalWins+(totalPushs*.5)),0) AS totalPoints,
    IFNULL(totalWins+totalLost+totalPushs,0) AS totalBets,
    IFNULL(totalWins+totalLost,0) AS trueBets
FROM users
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        userID,
        userName,
        SUM(win) AS totalWins,
        SUM(lost) AS totalLost,
        SUM(push) AS totalPushs
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            (finalResult = 'win') AS win,
            (finalResult = 'loss') AS lost,
            (finalResult = 'push') AS push
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                users.userID,
                userName,
                IF (pickID=visitorID, visitorResult, homeResult) AS finalResult
            FROM
                users
            JOIN
                picks 
            ON
                users.userID = picks.userID
            JOIN
                schedule
            ON
                picks.gameID = schedule.gameID
            WHERE
                weekNum <= 1
        ) x
    ) x
    GROUP BY
        userID
) lt
ON
    users.userID = lt.userID
LIMIT 100
```

I've not tested this, but the main change is to start at the `users` table and then join your results on. Your issue previously is because you are starting at your results and trying to join the `users` and, where the user has not made any picks, they are returning as null. This way should cause the results to be null but display all users as your starting point is there so you will pull all records